# In C#, why can't I test if a event handler is null anywhere outside of the class that it's defined?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, delegates

I am sure that I am just not understanding something fundamental about events and/or delegates in C#, but why can't I do the Boolean tests in this code sample:

```
public class UseSomeEventBase {
    public delegate void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;
    protected void OnSomeEvent(EventArgs e) {
        // CANONICAL WAY TO TEST EVENT. OF COURSE, THIS WORKS.
        if (SomeEvent != null) SomeEvent(this, e);
    }
}

public class UseSomeEvent : UseSomeEventBase {
    public bool IsSomeEventHandlerNull() {
        // "LEFT HAND SIDE" COMPILER ERROR
        return SomeEvent == null;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var useSomeEvent = new UseSomeEvent();
        useSomeEvent.SomeEvent +=new UseSomeEventBase.SomeEventHandler(FuncToHandle);
        // "LEFT HAND SIDE" COMPILER ERROR
        if (useSomeEvent.SomeEvent == null) {

        }
        var useSomeEventBase = new UseSomeEventBase();
        useSomeEventBase.SomeEvent += new UseSomeEventBase.SomeEventHandler(FuncToHandle);
        // "LEFT HAND SIDE" COMPILER ERROR
        if (useSomeEventBase.SomeEvent == null) {

        }
    }

    static void FuncToHandle(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

Comment: quick question: do you need to do something specific with the event itself, or just to remove it from the control? If you just want to remove the event from the control, there's a quick hack: to check if the control is null. If that's the case, you don't need to worry about the event itself.

Comment: @Gabriel Marius Popescu I write this question a decade ago and don't remember what I was trying to do.  Thanks for hack suggestion though.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

An event is really just an "add" operation and a "remove" operation. You can't get the value, you can't set the value, you can't call it - you can just subscribe a handler for the event (`add`) or unsubscribe one (`remove`). This is fine - it's encapsulation, plain and simple. It's up to the publisher to implement add/remove appropriately, but unless the publisher chooses to make the details available, subscribers can't modify or access the implementation-specific parts.

*Field-like events* in C# (where you don't specify the add/remove bits) hide this - they create a variable of a delegate type *and* an event. The event's add/remove implementations just use the variable to keep track of the subscribers.

Inside the class you refer to the variable (so you can get the currently subscribed delegates, execute them etc) and outside the class you refer to the event itself (so only have add/remove abilities).

The alternative to field-like events is where you explicitly implement the add/remove yourself, e.g.

```
private EventHandler clickHandler; // Normal private field

public event EventHandler Click
{
    add
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New subscriber");
        clickHandler += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lost a subscriber");
        clickHandler -= value;
    }
}
```

See [my article on events](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html) for more information.

Of course the event publisher *can* also make more information available - you could write a property like `ClickHandlers` to return the current multi-cast delegate, or `HasClickHandlers`to return whether there are any or not. That's not part of the core event model though.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Just to add to it, you can, of course, implement the add/remove operations as explicit methods with a multi-cast delegate internally. In which case, you can track subscribers and un-subscribers yourself - and thus provide access to additional information (e.g. count of subscribers, etc) - if you so choose.

Comment: It might be useful to note that the *reason* events are implemented this way is so that any class cannot willy-nilly change the behaviour of the class with the event by simply accessing the event (like a delegate property) and wiping out it's list of subscribers.

Comment: @womp: I think that's covered by the encapsulation side - and my linked article. Will add a sentence to the first paragraph to make sure.

Comment: should be "... public **event** EventHandler Click ..."

Answer (score 19):

You can easily use a very simple approach here to not repeatedly subscribe to an event.

Either of the 2 approaches below can be used:

1. **Flag approach** : _getWarehouseForVendorCompletedSubscribed is a private variable initialized to false.

   ```
       if (!_getWarehouseForVendorCompletedSubscribed)
       {
           _serviceClient.GetWarehouseForVendorCompleted += new EventHandler<GetWarehouseForVendorCompletedEventArgs>(_serviceClient_GetWarehouseForVendorCompleted);
           _getWarehouseForVendorCompletedSubscribed = true;
       }
   ```
2. **Unsubscribe Approach** :Include an unsubscribe everytime you want to subscribe.

   ```
   _serviceClient.GetWarehouseForVendorCompleted -= new 
       EventHandler<GetWarehouseForVendorCompletedEventArgs>  
    (_serviceClient_GetWarehouseForVendorCompleted);


   _serviceClient.GetWarehouseForVendorCompleted += new 
          EventHandler<GetWarehouseForVendorCompletedEventArgs>
          (_serviceClient_GetWarehouseForVendorCompleted);
   ```

Comment: +1 This is BRILLIANT and this is exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand why this did not get more votes

Comment: For the unsubscribe approach, how can you 'remove' a new EventHandler if it's not already added?

Comment: If it hasn't been added, it will simply ignore the -=

Answer (score 4):

Here the answer:

```
using System;
delegate void MyEventHandler();
class MyEvent
{
    string s;
    public event MyEventHandler SomeEvent;
    // This is called to raise the event.
    public void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null)
        {
            SomeEvent();
        }

    }

    public string IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            if (SomeEvent != null)
                 return s = "The EventHandlerList is not NULL";
            else return s = "The EventHandlerList is NULL"; ;
        }
    }
}

class EventDemo
{  
    // An event handler.
    static void Handler()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Event occurred");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
       MyEvent evt = new MyEvent();
       // Add Handler() to the event list.
       evt.SomeEvent += Handler;
       // Raise the event.
       //evt.OnSomeEvent();
       evt.SomeEvent -= Handler;
       Console.WriteLine(evt.IsNull);
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different question

> What value is there in testing an externally defined event for null?

As an external consumer of an event you can only do 2 operations

- Add a handler
- Remove a handler

The null or non-nullness of the event has no bearing on these 2 actions.  Why do you want to run a test which provides no perceivable value?

Comment: i am trying to write a wrapper work-around class for 2 poorly designed third-party web controls that i am required to use for a project (i hate this crazy controls). i'm trying to enforce the use of a specific method as the event handler for an event in a member object (reference to one of the web controls) of a class (the wrapper). i want to do a check in the wrapper class to ensure that user of the wrapper class has added a specific event handler to an event of the member object. it's very specific to this 2 stupid controls and hard to explain...

Comment: Why would we assume there was no perceivable value? The direct value is information - it answers the question "are there subscribers?". The value of that information is entirely dependent on the work being done. In my case I would like to test from a derived class if the handler in the base class has no handlers attached. Because the derived class is running an expensive loop and raising an event on the base, and it has no reason to run the loop unless/until there are subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rule in place when using the 'event' keyword. When you create an event, you are restricting outside class interaction with the delegate to a "subscribe / unsubscribe" relationship, this includes cases of inheritance. Remember an event is essentially a property, but for method calls, it isn't really an object itself, so really it looks more like this:

```
public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent
{
     add
     {
          //Add method call to delegate
     }
     remove
     {
          //Remove method call to delegate
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do that from the base class.  That's the exact reason that you did this:

```
protected void OnSomeEvent(EventArgs e) {
    // CANONICAL WAY TO TEST EVENT. OF COURSE, THIS WORKS.
    if (SomeEvent != null) SomeEvent(this, e);
}
```

You can't access events from a derived class.  Also, you should make that method virtual, so that it can be overridden in a derived class.

Comment: Be aware that that's not threadsafe. It can throw a NullReferenceException if the last handler is removed after the test but before the invocation.

Comment: @Jon - i did read your article about this, but i don't think this would happen in this web app.

Answer (score 0):

Publisher of the event implicitly overload only `+=` and `-=` operations, and other operations are not implemented in the publisher because of the obvious reasons as explained above, such as don't want to give control to subscriber to change events.

If we want to validate if a particular event is subscribed in the subscriber class, better publisher will set a flag in its class when event is subscriber and clear the flag when it is unsubscriber.

If subscriber can access the flag of publisher, very easily identifiable whether the particular event is subscriber or not by checking the flag value.