# List all asp.net controls that have a matching onclick attribute after one is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a bunch of `LinkButton`s on an asp.net page and need to set the visibility property of all the other `LinkButton`s on the page that have the same onclick attribute.  I'm looking for a server side solution.

In the click handler I've gotten as far as listing the `LinkButton`s on the `Page` recursively but am stumped at how to tell if each `LinkButton` I find does or doesn't have a matching click handler.

The `EventHandler` property doesn't seem to contain any good info...

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Just to confirm - you're looking for server-side `onclick` property that has server-side event handler - not the client-side click attribute?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter that is correct.  It's a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ugly solution would be to give all of those buttons the same CommandName attribute. Then you can just search for all link buttons with that attribute. Otherwise I am not sure that there is a great way to track the event handler used by each LinkButton.

Comment: Everything I've tried so far has been ugly...  I'll look at this option. Thanks.

Comment: Further reading on how event handlers work lead me to believe this is the best I can do with the page as it currently exists without a major rewrite.  So I'll accept this answer.    This question helped:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212721/check-if-the-control-has-events-on-click-eventhandler

Answer (score 1):

You can give your linkbuttons a custom atttribute (for simplicity it can be the same as event handler name) e.g.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton_Click" tag="LinkButton_Click">LinkButton1</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton_Click" tag="LinkButton_Click">LinkButton2</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in your server-side code you can simple compare the attributes

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your recursive code retrieving current linkbutton 
    // ...
    if ((sender as LinkButton).Attributes["tag"] == currentLinkbutton.Attributes["tag"]) 
    {
       // do your magic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try linkbtn.Attributes["OnClick"]

Comment: After looping thru the keys for the Attributes collections for all the linkbuttons it doesn't look like "OnClick" is stored here...  Thanks for the idea tho.