# C# Know how many EventHandlers are set?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

As we all know, we can create an EventHandler and add methods to it N number of times. Like:

```
   // Declare and EventHandler     
   public event EventHandler InternetConnectionAvailableEvent;
    private void OnInternetConnectionAvailableEvent()
    {
        if (InternetConnectionAvailableEvent != null)
        {
            EventHandler handle = InternetConnectionAvailableEvent;

            EventArgs e = EventArgs.Empty;
            handle(this, e);
        }
    }


   // IN OTHER CLASS WHERE I USE THE EVENT
   // Set the method name to handle the event    
   monitorInternet.InternetConnectionAvailableEvent += HandleInternetConnectionEvent;

    void HandleInternetConnectionEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (syncContext != null)
        {
            MonitorInternetConnection mic = (MonitorInternetConnection)sender;
            if (mic != null)
            {
                syncContext.Post(o => InternetConnected(), null);
            }
        }
    }

   // To remove
   monitorInternet.InternetConnectionAvailableEvent -= null;
```

**UPDATE :**

```
   // To remove it should be 
   monitorInternet.InternetConnectionAvailableEvent -= HandleInternetConnectionEvent;  // CORRECT
```

Same method can be called multiple times without removing it.

If I make `monitorInternet.InternetConnectionAvailableEvent -= null;`, all the event handlers be removed. I mean if it is set 2-3 times, and removed only once, by making it null, also all the other methods will be removed automatically.

I believe it will, but I just wanted to confirm with you experts. While googling I didn't get my required satisfactory answer.

Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To find the number of event handlers, you can use this code:

```
InternetConnectionAvailableEvent.GetInvocationList().Length;
```

The following code demonstrates that `MyEvent -= null` does not clear the list of handlers.

```
public static event EventHandler MyEvent;

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   MyEvent += (s,dea) => 1.ToString();
   MyEvent -= null;

   Console.WriteLine(MyEvent.GetInvocationList().Length);
   // Prints 1
   MyEvent = null;
   Console.WriteLine(MyEvent == null);
   // Prints true
}
```

To clear the list (which is probably never a good idea), you can set the event to null (as long as you are in the class that declared the event).

Comment: OR can also do a for loop and MyEvent -= HandlerMethod (the one we use with +=), right. And make MyEvent = null. These 2 options can solve my query. Am I right. Am not good with delegates, get confused at tiems. So am asking to confirm.

Comment: Corrected error in code by changing identificator `x` to `MyEvent`

Answer (score 4):

Delegates are removed by equality, so you're not removing anything from the invocation list because nothing in the invocation list would be `null`.

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is a field-like event. It is the same as the longhand event declaration, except no body.

From inside the class, you can set the event to null. From outside the class you cannot do this. Events follow a subscribe and unsubscribe methodology. Within the class you reference the variable, outside the class you reference the event.

See this answer by [Jon Skeet on events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246116/in-c-why-cant-i-test-if-a-event-handler-is-null-anywhere-outside-of-the-class/1246149#1246149).