# Count number of subscribers to a publisher from a separate class? How to get reference to InvocationList of Handler from a different class?

Tags: c#, events

I have a C# project where there are a number of events. So, there a number of publisher and a number of subscribers that subscribe to that event. What I want is to keep a count of subscribers to each of the publishers.

For simplicity, I have created a basic scenario here. In this example, I want to count the number of subscribers to each publisher in Class EventsCounter. I have a number of questions here.

1. Is there anyway to know how many events are there in the project or will I have to list them manually in Class EventsCounter?
2. How do I get reference to the handler in each Events?
3. Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Here, I could use the InvocationList but I could not reference the handler from a different class. e.g. Publisher.Foo gave me an error.

```
    using System;

    namespace EventTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                GenerateEvents ge = new GenerateEvents();
            }
        }

        public class EventsCounter
        {
            //need to count all events and corresponding subscribers here
        }

        public class GenerateEvents
        {
            public GenerateEvents()
            {
                Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
                Subscriber subscriber1 = new Subscriber();
                Subscriber subscriber2 = new Subscriber();

                publisher.Foo += subscriber1.FooHandler;
                publisher.Foo += subscriber2.FooHandler;
                publisher.RaiseFoo();

                publisher.Foo -= subscriber1.FooHandler;
                publisher.Foo -= subscriber2.FooHandler;
                publisher.RaiseFoo();

                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        public class Publisher
        {
            public event EventHandler Foo;
            int count = 0;

            public void RaiseFoo()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Raising Foo");
                EventHandler handler = Foo;

                if (handler != null)
                {
                    foreach (EventHandler subscriber in handler.GetInvocationList())
                    {
                        count++;
                        subscriber(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("The count is {0}", count);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No subscribers!");
                }
            }
        }

        public class Subscriber
        {
            public void FooHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Subscriber Called");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Know how many EventHandlers are set !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439621/c-sharp-know-how-many-eventhandlers-are-set)

Comment: I cannot use Publisher.Foo in another class. I can only use to subscribe and unsubscribe i.e. (+= and -+)

Comment: Why not add a `SubscriberCount` property to the `Publisher` class where you can use `GetInvocationList()`?

Comment: Then I have to have instance of Publisher or make SubscriberCount  static. In either case, wouldn't it keeps the publisher alive and which in turn will create subscribers alive and create memory problems.

Answer (score 1):

You might declare a property of type Event. This way, you can track subscription to and removal from your event.
Also, you can enumerate through subscribed handlers by calling your event's `GetInvocationList()` method. I demonstrated this within the publisher's `EnumerateSubscribers()` method.
Below code is a demonstration:

```
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Publisher();
            var s1 = new Subscriber("first");
            s1.Subscribe(p);
            p.RaiseFoo(null, null);
            var s2 = new Subscriber("second");
            s2.Subscribe(p);
            p.RaiseFoo(null, null);
            p.EnumerateSubscribers();
            s1.Unsubscribe(p);
            p.RaiseFoo(null, null);
            s2.Unsubscribe(p);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Subscriber
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Subscriber(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public void Subscribe(Publisher p)
        {
            p.Foo += this.HandleFoo;
        }

        public void Unsubscribe(Publisher p)
        {
            p.Foo -= this.HandleFoo;
        }

        private void HandleFoo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Name + " is called");
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }

    public class Publisher
    {
        private int count;
        private EventHandler _foo;

        public void RaiseFoo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_foo != null)
            {
                _foo(sender, e);
            }
        }

        public void EnumerateSubscribers()
        {
            if (_foo != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in _foo.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Subscriber object:" + item.Target?.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler Foo
        {
            add
            {
                _foo += value;
                Console.WriteLine("Count:" + ++count);
            }

            remove
            {
                _foo -= value;
                Console.WriteLine("Count:" + --count);
            }
        }
    }


}
```